# Provided dependencies for _deploy.jar java_binary

Tags: java, bazel

I want to migrate a maven project to Bazel. In maven, I have some dependencies declared as `provided`. It means the dependency is used to compile but is not shipped in the final jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a way to declare dependencies as `provided` in Bazel for a java binary that are not in the `_deploy.jar` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [`java_library.deps`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library.deps) may be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [compile-only dependencies](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external#compile-only-dependencies) provided by [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external).

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:specs.bzl", "maven")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        maven.artifact("org.apache.spark", "spark-core_2.11", "<spark.version>", neverlink = True),
    ],
)
```